# How to find difference between two date of same columns with same day?

Tags: php, mysql

i have table named attendance which consists record of employees.
[image]

what i want to do is to find the difference between date or i want to find working hours of the day of the employees .. 
I am using Php and Mysql database.
can any one help me?

Comment: What did you tried ? Please share your code.

Comment: This will be seriously tricky to do in MySQL alone. What you could do is group these by day and then into pairs, but you will probably have gaps, missing data, and other things that will severely complicate this.

Comment: You would also need a column to indicate if each is a punch in or punch out to do this effectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming an employee only punches in/out twice a day, you can use `GROUP BY` with `TIMEDIFF` and `DATE` functions to calculate working hours for a day, e.g.:

```
SELECT empid, DATE(punch_date) as date, TIMEDIFF(MAX(punch_date), MIN(punch_date)) as hours
FROM records
GROUP BY empid, DATE(punch_date);
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/19519af/2/0)**.

Comment: i am using yii2 framework . i tried this  
             $data=\app\models\HrmAttendenceRecord::findBySql('SELECT 
    emp_id, DATE(punch_date) as date, TIMEDIFF(MAX(punch_date), 
    MIN(punch_date)) as hours
    FROM hrm_attendence_record WHERE  punch_date between 
    "'.$from.'" AND "'.$to.'"
    GROUP BY emp_id, DATE(punch_date);')->all();
but it only returns Null except emp_id  why is that?  
i am trying to generate the monthly report

Answer (score 0):

Definitely do the calculation in PHP - don't try to make this work in SQL alone. You cannot handle exceptions/invalid input in SQL.

*Note: For this answer I assume every employee has exactly 2 entries on working dates (e.g. no lunch break punch) and also that working times start and end on the same date.*

I would create a simple php function that returns the working hours of 1 employee for 1 day, e.g.

```
/**
 * @param  int    $emp_id Numeric employee ID, e.g. 156
 * @param  string $date   The date as 10 character string e.g. "2017-03-16"
 * @return int    The working time, in seconds. e.g. 8 hours = 28800 seconds.
 */
function get_working_hours( $emp_id, $date ) {}
```

Then retrieve the times for that employee from the SQL DB, e.g.

```
$sql = sprintf(
  "SELECT punch_date FROM `%s` WHERE emp_id = %d AND punch_date LIKE '%s %%'",
  'table_name',
  (int) $emp_id,
  mysqli_real_escape_string( substr( $date, 0, 10 ) )
);
// Result SQL looks like:
// SELECT punch_date FROM `table` WHERE emp_id = 156 AND punch_date LIKE '2017-03-16 %'
```

Next run the SQL and check, if you have exactly 2 results.

```
// Get the results from DB, I assume you use mysqli:
$result = mysqli_query( $db_link, $sql );

if ( mysqli_num_rows( $result ) != 2 ) { 
  // either invalid punches (too many or only 1), or not punched at all.
  return 0; 
}
```

Finally you have exactly 2 punch dates. Now it's simple to calculate the difference:

```
$item1 = mysqli_fetch_row( $result );
$item2 = mysqli_fetch_row( $result );

// Convert the date string to a numeric timestamp:
$time1 = strtotime( $item1[0] );
$time2 = strtotime( $item2[0] );

// Calculate and return the difference:
return abs( $time1 - time2 ); // Return value is the working time in SECONDS!
```

Some parts are missing in this example, mostly the DB connection and some sanitation (e.g. are both input params correct? are both SQL return values correct time-strings? ...)